# populate select based from json response

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

hi so i have this select tag / dropdownlist that i needed to populate based from a json's output. the scenario is this, the user chooses a main category from a dropdown. then upon change of this dropdown i fetch the sub category data from the database based from the main category. in this point im successful in getting the subcategory data i'am displying the data in the console but it won't populate the dropdown here is my code

**dropdown for both main and subcategories**

```
<div>
      <label for="">Main Category</label>
      <select name="category" id="category">
          @foreach($categories as $category)
            <option value="{{$category->maincategoryid}}">{{$category->maincategoryname}}</option>
          @endforeach
      </select>
  </div>
 <div id="subcate">
      <label for="">Sub-Categories</label>
      <select name="sc" id="sc">
        <option value=""></option>
      </select>
  </div>
```

**then here is my script**

```
<script>  
      $('#category').on('change' , function(e)
      {
          console.log(e);
          var cat_id = e.target.value;
          // alert(cat_id);
          //ajax
          $.get('ajax-subcat?cat_id=' + cat_id, function(data)
          {

              $('#sc').empty();
              $.each(data, function(i, subcatObj)
              {
                  console.log(data[i].subcategoryname);
                  $('#sc').append('<option value="' + data[i].subcategoryid + '">' + data[i].subcategoryname + '</option>');
              });
          });

      });
  </script>
```

**sample output of console**

[image]

the thing is it does not append the data i am getting. any ideas on what i needed to do? thanks so much!

**note**

im currently using Material design and php framework Laravel 4.2

Comment: move `$('#sc').empty();` outside `$.get('ajax-subcat?cat_id=' + cat_id, function(data)`

Comment: hi @guradio i tried moving it before `$.get()` still not working tho

Comment: @guradio Why? This logic is correct. You get the subcategory data, clear the list and fill it in. @BourneShady, could you show the result of `ajax-subcat?cat-id=any` execution?

Comment: What does `console.log(data[i].subcategoryname);` log? proper values?

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev please see updated question i have posted the pic of the console thnks

Comment: @GuruprasadRao  please see updated question i have posted the pic of the console thnks

Comment: obvious question, but is "sc" definitely the id of the dropdown? I can't see any other reason it wouldn't work.

Comment: @ADyson yup the id that i used is "sc"

Comment: Can you print `$('#sc')` after `console.log(data[i].subcategoryname);` to see if it is successfully located?